# DDL Trigger to track SP events

Tags: sql-server

As I have use below trigger to track SP events log. How can I get specific line of query which was change in SP. Please find below trigger syntax for your reference. Request to provide your valuable suggestion.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DDLEvents
(
    EventDate    DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    EventType    NVARCHAR(64),
    EventDDL     NVARCHAR(MAX),
    EventXML     XML,
    DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255),
    SchemaName   NVARCHAR(255),
    ObjectName   NVARCHAR(255),
    HostName     VARCHAR(64),
    IPAddress    VARCHAR(48),
    ProgramName  NVARCHAR(255),
    LoginName    NVARCHAR(255)
);


CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER DDL_TRG_EVENT
    ON database
    FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE
        @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();
 
    DECLARE @ip varchar(48) = CONVERT(varchar(48), 
        CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address'));
 
    INSERT [dbo].[DDLEvents]
    (
        EventType,
        EventDDL,
        EventXML,
        DatabaseName,
        SchemaName,
        ObjectName,
        HostName,
        IPAddress,
        ProgramName,
        LoginName
    )
    SELECT
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',   'NVARCHAR(100)'), 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        @EventData,
        DB_NAME(),
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'), 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'),
        HOST_NAME(),
        @ip,
        PROGRAM_NAME(),
        SUSER_SNAME();
END
GO
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Provide an example of a changed procedure and what end result you expect.

Comment: Required to get the change line number in target table which are used in DDL Trigger so whenever there are some change is happening in SP we can track which specific line was change.